# Why doesn't align-items work in my body part of CSS file?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
<body>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="imgBox">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </div>
        <h2>Hello</h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is my HTML

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;

}

body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    background-color: aquamarine;

}

.card{
    width: 350px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: red;
}

.card .imgBox{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
   
}
```

I am beginner in CSS and try to figure out how flexbox works? When I try to center red box using align-items: center;, the box doesn't change its position.

Comment: "When I try to center red box using align-items: center" — Your code isn't trying to do that though. You should provide a [mcve]. Use the live demo feature of the question editor.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 8):

aling-items works only when parrent item has a height on it.

If you set a `height: 100vh` to body, It will work.

You can also change this behavior with adding some content to it.

You can also check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Layout_cookbook/Center_an_element

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use vh and vw.

Looks like:

```
h1 {
   font-size: 20vh;
}
```

For more Information about vh and vw: https://www.sitepoint.com/css-viewport-units-quick-start/